# Sharing machine learning models of a confidential dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Please share your thoughts about using machine learning models from confidential datasets. For example, I have a classification model I trained using `sklearn`. In general, can I use the model for similar purposes? Or does the owner of the confidential dataset automatically own the model too?

I've read that it depends on the **library** and **dataset** used whether information about the data can be inferred or not. I know for `sklearn` models, it cannot be. Can you please give me more examples as well?

I may seem to ask for legal advice but no, I just want to know more about this area. I'm not affiliated with any tech lawyer either, and I think that goes too far for a simple informal discussion.